# Creation of a time-only frequency in Python

Tags: python, pandas, time-series

I'm trying to generate a frequency DataFrame in Jupyter/Python of HH:MM:SS elements of a datetime column.

Aside from iterating over all HH:MM:SS combinations and counting them (I need to include 0 values), is there a function in Python that can do it for me?

`.value_counts()` creates what I need, however, 0 values are not included.

Many thanks, in advance, for your assistance :)

**EDIT**: sample data:

| TransactionID | DateTime | Date | Time |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 012sad9j20j | 01/01/22 04:23:32 | 01/01/22 | 04:23:32 |
| 938hfd82dj2 | 07/04/22 23:12:59 | 07/04/22 | 23:12:59 |
| s9j20jd902j | 18/05/22 13:44:19 | 18/05/22 | 13:44:19 |

Expected to generate a dataframe containing:

| Time | Count |
| --- | --- |
| 04:23:31 | 0 |
| 04:23:32 | 1 |
| 04:23:33 | 0 |

Comment: Since you're talking about a 'DataFrame', can we assume you're using `pandas`? (probably add that tag)  Have you tried anything at all? Your problem is fairly common and the pandas documentation and available guides and tutorials often tackle it? What exactly are you stuck on? Please share some code, but also provide an example (a few rows) of the data and what output you expect.

Comment: If `.value_counts()` is what you need, isn't the answer simply the result of `.value_counts()`, with an added row for 0 values, which would be the total number of rows in the original DataFrame, minus the total of values in the `.value_counts()` result?

Comment: Thanks both; I've edited to include the tag, yes, I am utilising pandas.

Essentially, I have a table of transactions each transaction with a datetime field. I have seperated this datetime element into a date column and a time column.

What I am wanting to do is create a summary dataframe counting all records for that specific time, however, there isnt a transaction for every single time element in a day.

The purpose is to create a line plot to show times of increased transactions, and also quietest periods.

Comment: My current plan is to iterate through each time element 00:00:00, 00:00:01, 00:00:02 etc counting rows - this is a long winded way and was hoping for something a lot more efficient.

I'm relatively new to Python and learning via Google, so I apologise if I am looking at this incorrectly (or even using SO incorrectly; I've had a few questions closed because of my errors!)

Comment: You can always change the dtype of your Time column to be a category, whose categorical values are all possible times.  The `value_counts` will then include the zero values.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a solution:

```
from pandas import DataFrame
from datetime import datetime, time

df = DataFrame([
    {'TransactionID': 'xyz1', 'DateTime': datetime(year=2022, month=6, day=16, hour=13, minute=1, second=2)},
    {'TransactionID': 'xyz1', 'DateTime': datetime(year=2022, month=6, day=16, hour=13, minute=3, second=4)},
    {'TransactionID': 'xyz1', 'DateTime': datetime(year=2022, month=6, day=17, hour=13, minute=5, second=6)},
    {'TransactionID': 'xyz1', 'DateTime': datetime(year=2022, month=6, day=18, hour=13, minute=1, second=2)},
    {'TransactionID': 'xyz1', 'DateTime': datetime(year=2022, month=6, day=19, hour=13, minute=3, second=4)}
])

times = DataFrame(df['DateTime'].dt.time).groupby(['DateTime'])['DateTime'].count()

time_counts = DataFrame((
    (t := time(h, m, s), int(times[t]) if t in times else 0)
    for h in range(24) for m in range(60) for s in range(60)
), columns=['Time', 'Counts'])
print(time_counts)

print(time_counts[time_counts['Time'] == time(13, 1, 2)])
```

This basically creates an additional DataFrame `times` based on the original data (assuming you don't even have a `Time` and `Date` column, but if you do, you can of course use those) - `times` takes all the times from `df` and then groups and counts them.

However, that is missing the times which don't occur in `df`, so `time_counts` is constructed by generated all possible times and either selecting the count from `times` or 0 if it doesn't exist in `times`.

Result:

```
           Time  Counts
0      00:00:00       0
1      00:00:01       0
2      00:00:02       0
3      00:00:03       0
4      00:00:04       0
...         ...     ...
86395  23:59:55       0
86396  23:59:56       0
86397  23:59:57       0
86398  23:59:58       0
86399  23:59:59       0

[86400 rows x 2 columns]
           Time  Counts
46862  13:01:02       2
```

User @riley's suggestion seems to point at a nicer solution, something like:

```
# create df as before, then:

df['Time'] = df['DateTime'].dt.time.astype('category')
result = df.value_counts('Time')
```

But that seems to have the same problem as you originally stated, even though the `dtype` of the `'Time'` column is `category`. Perhaps someone has additional suggestions to make that work.

Comment: Your first code snippet worked an absolute breeze - thanks so much.

Just to add, I wasnt able to plot these values straight away i received a "float() argument must be a string or a number, not 'datetime.time'" message

To fix this, I created an additional column which appended the current date to all rows using

time_counts['datetime'] = [datetime.datetime.combine(datetime.date.today(), t) for t in time_counts['Time']]